# css: Have a min-width that is possibly smaller than the max-width?

Tags: css

How would I produce the following...

I'd like my div to have a width of `400px`. However, if less than `400px` are available then I'd like it to have a width of `50%`. Is this possible using just CSS? I've tried setting `min-width` and `width` but it seems to always go with whichever is larger.

Comment: is it the resolution your talking about? or only the input inside the div that is less than 400px?

Comment: @Bert The resolution. If 400px are available fill it. Else take up 50% of the page width.

Comment: check my post below it can help you.. =D

Answer (score 0):

why not use

```
width:auto;
height: auto;
```

in your css??

If your for the resolution you can use Media queries

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
//put css on body that you want to apply
body{
width:auto;
}
//put css on div that you want to apply
.div{
width:auto;
}

}
```

it means smaller than 400px will have this css or adjust to what it contains.

Comment: because. I don't want it to take up anymore than 400px if more than 400px is available.

Comment: use media queries you can play around the css and feel free to ask

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  div { width: 400px; }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 399px) {
  div { width: 50%; }
}
```